# PhpStorm - shift+4 ($) not working for first letter

Tags: phpstorm

I'm having a very specific typing problem in PhpStorm 7. Whenever im starting a word, i cant type '$'. How I've managed to keep programming so far? I type any number and then I can type $, like '4$' then I erase 4 and keep typing.

Has anyone been throught this?

Comment: This sounds more like your OS/keyboard config issue. In any case: **what 3rd party plugins** (not bundled ones) do you have installed?

Comment: That was the problem. I uninstalled a few plugins and it all worked out!